# bashrc script to automatically create emacs server session on startup?

Tags: server

I want to have .bashrc check to see if an emacs server is currently running, and if not, start one. I know how to start the server but I am not sure how to check whether it is already running - should I just grep the processes for Emacs? Curious if anyone has something like this set up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The functionality is built into Emacs. Run [`emacsclient`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Invoking-emacsclient.html#Invoking-emacsclient) and pass it the `-a` (long form `--alternate-editor`) option with an empty argument, and it'll start Emacs (in daemon mode, i.e. initially without any window) if it isn't already running.

```
emacsclient -a ''                    # in sh syntax
emacsclient --alternate-editor=      # anywhere whitespace-separated command and arguments work
```

If you always use this command to open files, Set the `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables to it in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zprofile`:

```
export VISUAL='emacsclient --alternate-editor='
export EDITOR='emacsclient --alternate-editor='
```

and make an alias for it in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`:

```
alias e='emacsclient --alternate-editor='
```

Add the option `-c` if you want to open a new Emacs window to edit the file. With `emacsclient -c`, if you don't pass a file name argument, you get a new Emacs window showing whatever buffer is at the front of the buffer list.

Alternatively, run `emacs --daemon` as part of your session startup and use plain `emacsclient` to open files.

Note that `~/.bashrc` runs every time you open a terminal, not when you log in. On normal Unix systems, the file that runs when you log in is `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, etc. depending on your login shell), but [OSX does things differently](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-oth) (and actually runs `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` and not `~/.bashrc` when you open a terminal due to a combination of bad design in OSX and bad design in bash: OSX opens a login shell in each terminal and bash doesn't load `.bashrc` in login shells — see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110998/missing-source-bashrc-mac-terminal-profile).

Comment: I get the error "emacsclient: option '--alternate-editor' requires an argument" when I run `emacsclient --a ''` - perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean by empty argument?

Comment: @Andrew That's because you aren't actually passing the empty argument. You can't stuff an empty argument in the `EDITOR` variable, because you can't arrange to have an empty word there. That's why I showed the use of `--alternate-editor=`, which doesn't require an empty word.

Comment: Hmm I added the env variables and the alias and it still makes me specify a file before I can connect

Comment: @Andrew What commands are you using? What do you mean by “makes me specify a file before I can connect”? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I put those lines in my zshrc, and when I type `e` I get `macsclient: file name or argument required
Try emacsclient --help' for more information` - it is still asking me to specify a file. It works fine if I type `e filename`.

Comment: @Andrew Well, sure, to open a file, you need to specify the file's name. I guess you wanted to open a new Emacs window without opening a file? Pass the `-c` option.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you create a startup script, with the command `emacs --daemon` at startup. Then there is no need to start Emacs server anymore.

See also [this link](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon).

Which Linux distro are you running?

Comment: Primarily Ubuntu and osX (unix, not linux tho).